# Express return value from method with callback

Tags: node.js, express, callback

Why does this

```
router.get('/eventTest/:id', function (req, res) {

var event = Event.getEventById(req.params.id, function (err, rows) {
    if(err) {
        return err;
    } else {
        return rows;
    }
});

res.json(event);
```

});

returns 
`{
"domain": null,
"_events": {},
"_eventsCount": 0,
"_callSite": {},
"_ended": false,
"_idleNext": null,
"_idlePrev": null,
"_idleStart": null,
"_idleTimeout": -1,
"_repeat": null,
"sql": "select * from event where id=?",
"values": [
"1"
],
"typeCast": true,
"nestTables": false,
"_resultSet": null,
"_results": [],
"_fields": [],
"_index": 0,
"_loadError": null
}`

this and example of one of the methods that I'm calling

`getEventById:function(id,callback){

```
    return db.query("select * from event where id=?",[id],callback);
}
```

`

rather than the actual values like it does when I use res.json(rows) inside the Event.getEventById callback?

I need this in order to call multiple methods and add them to an object and then send that object in JSON

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your code, yes you need to send response from method.

Since as `Node.js` nature is `async` so you need to write your code in that way

Try it in your route

```
Event.getEventById(req.params.id, function (err, rows) {
    if(err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(rows);
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

> To execute multiple methods and send all records at single time then go through

[async module](https://github.com/caolan/async) or [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: It works, but my idea was to call multiple methods and assign the result to an object and then res.send that object.

For example:

`var event = {};

event.details = Event.getEventById(req.params.id, function (err, rows) {
        if(err) {
            return err;
        } else {
            return rows;
        }
    });

event.teams =Event.getEventStages(req.params.id, function (err, rows) {
        if(err) {
            return err;
        } else {
            return rows;
        }
    });

res.json(event);`

Comment: Yes, you can use `promise` or async module

Comment: Use [async.waterfall or series](https://github.com/caolan/async) to get your desire result

Comment: I tried express-promise and it still returned the query and not the results

Comment: Use [promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), write all your methods als at last call `all`, take the sample from link.

Hope that will work!!

Comment: should my method calls look like this?: 
`var event = new Promise(Event.getEventById(req.params.id, function (err, rows) {
        if(err) {
            return err;
        } else {
            return rows;
        }
    }));`

Comment: You need to continue with the answer and add the methods in your route and at last use all method.

Answer (score 1):

I tried "express-promise" like this:

```
`router.get('/eventTest/:id', function (req, res) {
    res.json({
       details: Event.getEventById(req.params.id),
       stages: Event.getEventStages(req.params.id)
    });
 });`
```

and still got the same result (i.e. the query and not the values). I'm guessing that my problem is the way that I managing the callbacks from the methods. Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/eventTest/:id', function (req, res, next) {

  Event.getEventById(req.params.id, function (err, rows) {
    if(err) 
        return next(err);

    res.json(rows);
  });
});
```